# Bookmarklet that adds a JavaScript function

Tags: bookmarklet, javascript

I am currently trying to make a bookmarklet that adds, among other things, a `DIV` element to the page.

I'm doing this by adding the HTML code to `body.innerHTML` and that works fine. On this `DIV` element is a button that should allow to hide the added `DIV`. I therefore tried to add via JavaScript a JavaScript function to the `innerHTML` called `function hideDiv()`.

The new JavaScript is added to the body and it looks fine. But it doesn't work.

Short example:

```
javascript:var b = document.body.InnerHTML; b=b+'<input type="button" onclick="javascript:alert("hello")"/>'; document.body.innerHTML = b;
```

This bookmarklet should add a button that shows an alert if its clicked. It adds the button but nothing happens when clicking on it.

Is this a general issue? Can JavaScript add (working) JavaScript to a page?

Comment: It's `innerHTML`, not `InnerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set an id and then just add the function to the element. Like this:

```
javascript:var b = document.body.InnerHTML; b=b+'<input type="button" id="test"/>'; document.body.innerHTML = b; document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () { alert('hi')}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `javascript:` prefix is only used in `href` attributes (or `action` for forms). It is NOT used in `onclick` or any other events. Remove the `javascript:` and your code should work fine.